# In C++, how do I correctly load a file into an array of wider than char data types?

Tags: c++

Specifically, I'm trying to program an FPGA with a binary file.  The transaction register is 16-bits wide.  So I need to create an array of uint16_t and fill it with an input file.  Here is what I tried:

```
int bufferSize = 512;
uint16_t buffer[bufferSize];
std::ifstream *pStream = new std::ifstream( filepath );
if( pStream->is_open() == true )
{
   pStream->read( (char *)buffer, bufferSize );
}
```

From what I can tell through GDB, it seems each array node is backwards (ie. expected 0xBEEF, got 0xEFBE)

Comment: BTW: `if( pStream->is_open() == true )` is kind of prolix.

Comment: @TonyK Agreed. I'm under coding style constraints :P  It bugs me too.  "If is open" sounds quite explicit.

Comment: You should also use `pStream->read( (char*)buffer, bufferSize*sizeof(uint16_t) );` otherwise you will write only half of the data you were expecting to write. But the real problem is of course Big vs Little Endianness, as suggested below.

Comment: Thanks Mikael.  I indeed was getting less data than expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you've run into an endianness issue. You may need to use `htons()` or alike to get the endianness you desire. (use it on every element of the array, e.g. with a loop or `std::transform`). See http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/htonsman.html for some more detail.

Comment: These tools have a Unix background, big endian isn't unlikely.

Comment: Careful though. If the final destination for the data is the same as the input then you might not want to convert it. I don't know the details but if the file gets loaded into an array and pushed out to a programmer, double check what the file source and programmer use for endian.

Comment: Big endian swap was needed.  Thank you etarion